# Meaning of "call" in "close call"

Tags: meaning

"Close call" can basically be translated as "narrow escape", however, I couldn't find a definition of "call" that would be suitable for this situation. Does "call" (noun) have a meaning of "escape" or something similar? Feels very unintuitive to me as a non-native speaker.

Comment: Baseball.  A "call" is a decision by the umpire.

Comment: And note that you may still hear "close call" used to mean "difficult decision to make".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Close call:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/close+call)   (the call in this expression derives from the meaning '[decision](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/call)' in the context of sport)

> - also, **close shave** . Narrow escape, near miss. For example, That skier just missed the tree—what a close call , or That was a close shave, nearly leaving your passport behind .
>
>   - The first phrase (close call) dates from the late 1800s and comes from sports, alluding to an official's decision ( call ) that could have gone either way.
>   - The second ( close shave),  from the early 1800s, alludes to the narrow margin between closely shaved skin and a razor cut. (This latter usage replaced the much earlier equation of a close shave with miserliness, based on the idea that a close shave by a barber meant one would not have to spend money on another shave quite so soon.)

(from dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: [Etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=close) - I assume close is called to adjust when artillery hits close to the target

Comment: It is not clear from what Etymonline means alluding  to The American Civil War context. I find the American Heritage Dictionary assumption more interesting. (Just IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the etymology of the idiom, it's just one of those formulaic, commonplace expressions people jut use. Many an idiom and phrasal verb sound very counterintuitive for non-English speakers, but at some point, after living "in the language" for a long time, they take hold and you just use them, in the absence of anything better. I was actually looking for a less corny way of saying "after a few close calls"... For a replacement!